# Saving all credit card information including CCV!?

Tags: credit-card

I have been working on a project where other developers developed an app which processes credit cards. It's like the customer calls the representative and he takes the information and charges the card. We need to store reference to the card so we can charge them again quickly when they call us. It's infrequent and actually when the customer calls or make an order using on-line form.

When i was checking the database. I was very surprised to see that he was storing all credit card information. Well, not only the credit card number, he is also saving the expiration , ccv and everything a customer throws in.

It's all unencrypted and just there!We don't maintain that much monitoring/security  at all.

I am just all confused now. Is it ever okay to store them? I know it isn't . Whats his reason of storing them?

Comment: companies store Credit card info all the time...as for CCV and having it all just "there" not so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of strange. To be allowed to handle credit card data, you normally would have to pass an external PCI-DSS audit which would check the security of your system, including data handling, encryption, and processes.

The guidelines state amongst other things, that this data *has* to be encrypted. Also you are never allowed to store the CCV value. You should check with your colleagues is this is all kosher. You could face some serious (law-enforcement) issues if there are any issues on your system.

I guess the reason for storing the data like it's done today is just stupidity. You should really change that ASAP!

Comment: we sure use payment processor to process the payments. I am going to talk about this. But, he is a senior. I need enough grounds.

Comment: If you use a payment processor, you should just forward the data to him. But you are not allowed to save the data, at leat unless you have complete a PCI audit. To ensure the security of the saved credit card data is the single most important reason why there are these audits

Comment: Repeat, *never* store the CCV. The whole point is that this is information that is only discoverable *from the card itself*. There is *no* reason for you to store it, and as Holger says you are in breach of the PCI-DSS guidelines. That's a significant risk for your organization. In the event of a breach of your security, the bank has a reason to not cover you for your losses.